# rlp decoding not working as expected

Tags: smartpy

I have a rlp encoded data and am trying to decode it with Accurast library

```
Utils = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/main/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py")

data = "0xf8c8b83d6274703a2f2f30783232382e6172637469632f307831313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131b8396274703a2f2f3078312e69636f6e2f6378303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030348362747381f6b846f844b83d6274703a2f2f30783232382e6172637469632f307861313434326339303132304138393163336465393739336361433730393638436162313133323335c483627473"
decode_string(sp.bytes(data))
```

the output is not being shown as expected  the output is showing something like this,
'�=btp://0x228.arctic/0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111�

, how can we solve this ?

Comment: Update: I had to encode_list instead of encode_string, but there are certain prefixes that are being added on each element of the list, actual expected value was ["0x6274703a2f2f30783232382e6172637469632f307831313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131","0x6274703a2f2f3078312e69636f6e2f637830303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303034","0x627473","0xf6","0xf844b83d6274703a2f2f30783232382e6172637469632f307861313434326339303132304138393163336465393739336361433730393638436162313133323335c483627473"]

Comment: I got the following value with some values added as a prefix , what are these prefixes , 
{0 : sp.bytes('0xb83d6274703a2f2f30783232382e6172637469632f307831313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131'), 1 : sp.bytes('0xb8396274703a2f2f3078312e69636f6e2f637830303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303034'), 2 : sp.bytes('0x83627473'), 3 : sp.bytes('0x81f6'), 4 : sp.bytes('0xb846f844b83d6274703a2f2f30783232382e6172637469632f307861313434326339303132304138393163336465393739336361433730393638436162313133323335c483627473')}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Strings/Lists` with more than 55 in length were being incorrectly encoded.

I submitted a [MR](https://github.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/pull/2) that fixes the issue.

You can test the encodings with: https://codechain-io.github.io/rlp-debugger

The following example should now produce the correct encoding.

```
import smartpy as sp

Utils = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/main/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py")

@sp.add_test("Tests")
def test():
 sc = sp.test_scenario()
    
 link = "btp://0x228.arctic/0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
 encode_string = sp.build_lambda(Utils.RLP.Encoder.encode_string)
 rlpEncodedString = encode_string(link)
    
 sc.show(rlpEncodedString)
    
 decode_string = sp.build_lambda(Utils.RLP.Decoder.decode_string)
 sc.show(decode_string(rlpEncodedString))
```